# Exporting data to a .sql format. How to escape?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite, escaping

I'm writing an export tool that converts input json data to sql statements.

This tool is (and should not) be aware of database connections, it should just output a .sql that can be used with other tools do the actual import.

Most of the mysqli->* and PDO-related functions rely on an open connection (to determine things like the characterset). What's a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the MySQL functions require a connection in order to escape the string is that all [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) does is make a call to MySQL's built-in escaping function.

However, if you read [the manual page for it](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), you'll see that they do list the characters which are escaped:

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

You don't want to use `addslashes()` since that only escapes a few characters, and would not provide a secure solution. But you should be able to re-implement the escaping done by `mysql_real_escape_string()` using the list of characters given, with a simple call to [`strtr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) or similar:

```
$replacements = array("\x00"=>'\x00',
                      "\n"=>'\n',
                      "\r"=>'\r',
                      "\\"=>'\\\\',
                      "'"=>"\'",
                      '"'=>'\"',
                      "\x1a"=>'\x1a');
$escaped = strtr($unescaped,$replacements);
```

Answer (score 0):

For escaping, `mysql_real_escape_string` function is the usual choice for this task except it does need a connection. The other alternative would be `addslashes`.

I would check out a mysqldump file tailored with the needed paramaters (character sets, drop tables, etc ..) and take it from there as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

@stefgosselin:
mysql_real_escape_string did require a connection.

I would go the line with least resistance. Means use a systemcall to exec mysqldumper > tmpfile

Comment: The problem is that the source data is not at all SQL based. I'm importing from a CalDAV server and want something that can easily injected in (my) databasetables. To keep the unix philosophy I don't want to insert records directly.

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, is it possible for you app to generate and sql like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, name) VALUES (?, ?);
```

and pass a set of paramaters for the sql as an array

```
$parms = array('value1', 'value2');
```

and then have the part of your app that does do database work do the escaping at that point

```
function writeToDb($sql, $parms) {
// do escaping here
}
```

Comment: No, my idea is that I want to generate a 'plain' sql file.